# How to use a parameter passed to View in its ViewModel? SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I can't get my head around this.

I pass a the `conversationId: String` to my `ConversationView` which is usable inside the View. But I want to use it in my ViewModel.

How to I access it?

> ConversationView.Swift

```
struct ConversationView: View {
    var conversationId: String
        
    var body: some View {
        Text(conversationId)        
    }
}
```

> ConversationViewModel.Swift

```
extension ConversationView {
    @MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        init() {
           // print("dikken", self.conversationId)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it inside view model and inject view model itself, that would be MVVM

```
@MainActor class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var conversationId: String = "" // or what ever initial
}
```

and now

```
struct ConversationView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()  // if internal owner
//    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel  // if external owner
        
    var body: some View {
        Text(vm.conversationId)        // << here !!
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, if I remove the var from my view obviously this won't work any more.
`ConversationView(conversationId: inboxRow.id)`

How do I pass this variable?

Comment: Some more context:
`ForEach(viewModel.inbox!.conversations, id: \.self) { inboxRow in
                            NavigationLink {
                                ConversationView(conversationId: inboxRow.id)
                            } label: {
                                InboxRowView(inboxRow: inboxRow)
                            }
                        }`

Comment: Sorry for indenting.

Comment: Use `ObservedObject` variant and create view model with injected conversationId init, like `ConversationView(vm: ViewModel(id: inboxRow.id))`, assuming you will add corresponding `ViewModel.init(id:)`

Comment: Hmm, oke. I have the data this way. But via this approach my api calls get called as well. Which I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Moving these api calls to an onAppear doesn't feel right for me as well.

Comment: When you ask a question, try to stay within the bounds of the question and the example you showed. If you have an issue with other elements of your code, ask a new question. Answers get lost in the comments, and no one has a good frame of reference to answer without seeing the code anyway. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)